# How to get the xpath of a certain node when viewing an xml file in Visual Studio?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xpath

When I open an xml file in Visual Studio and browse it, I want to get the xpath of a certain node at the cursor like right click and choose "get xpath from this node" or something like that. How can we do that in Visual Studio 2010 or which tools/addons to use to do that?

Hope to hear from you all.

Answer (score 20):

I am unsure of a Visual Studio tool that does this (Although I am sure there is one). For me, I use Notepad++ (Is there anything it can't do!?).

1. Inside Notepad++ go to Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager
2. Install XML Tools
3. Restart Notepad
4. Load your XML Doc
5. Place your cursor onto the node you are looking to generate the xpath for
6. Go Plugins -> XML Tools -> Current XML Path (Default Hotkey : Ctrl + Alt + Shift + P)

This will only be able to give you the very basic XML tree traversal, but it's a start.

No tool will be able to generate any sort of complicated xPath for attribute checking etc. For those things often it is trial and error. You can use an online xPath tester to test your expressions against your XML anytime. Something like http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html should be a great help.

Comment: This tool doesn't work for me. It just returns "no result". Seems i'm not the only one with this issue

Comment: You XML must be valid for this to work. If your not getting the expected result, likely you have XML error. Same for the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

The extension you want is called "XPath Information". In Visual Studio go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online -> Search for "XPath Information".