# How to calculate the XPath to the current TextMate cursor in an XML file

Tags: xml, unix, xslt, xpath, textmate

I develop XSLT stylesheets using TextMate to transform large XML files (FileMaker fmxmlsnippet files). I often have the problem, that I have found an element or attribute in the XML file that I then need to reference within the XSLT.

The abstract question is:

Given an XML file being displayed in a text editor, with the cursor at position P, what algorithm (or technology) can be used to calculate an XPath expression to retrieve the node, attribute or text data at/around the cursor?

Here is an example of (the start of) a FileMaker fmxmlsnippet of a layout containing a portal.

```
<fmxmlsnippet type="LayoutObjectList">
<Layout enclosingRectTop="288.0000000" enclosingRectLeft="167.0000000" enclosingRectBottom="453.0000000" enclosingRectRight="482.0000000">
    <Object type="Portal" key="88" LabelKey="0" flags="0" rotation="0">
        <Bounds top="288.0000000" left="167.0000000" bottom="453.0000000" right="482.0000000"/>
        <PortalObj portalFlags="141" numOfRows="4" initialRow="2">
            <TableAliasKey>Ext.Ref.Manda|nten</TableAliasKey>
            <SortList>
                <Sort type="Ascending">
                    <Name>Ext.Ref.Mandanten::Mandant Nr</Name>
                </Sort>
                <Sort type="Descending">
                    <Name>Ext.Ref.Mandanten::DateField</Name>
                </Sort>
            </SortList>
            <FilterCalc>
                <Calculation><![CDATA[Ext.Ref.Mandanten::id >0]]></Calculation>
            </FilterCalc>
            <Styles>
                <LocalCSS>
                    ...
```

The cursor (shown as a pipe character) is currently standing within the data of the TableAliasKey element. I would like a function which returns a simple XPath to this text:

```
/fmxmlsnippet/Layout/Object/PortalObj/TableAliasKey/text()
```

If the cursor is standing (anywhere) within an attribute, e.g.:

```
<fmxmlsnippet type="LayoutObjectList">
<Layout enclosingRectTop="288.0000000" enclosingRectLeft="167.0000000" enclosingRectBottom="453.0000000" enclosingRectRight="482.0000000">
    <Object type="Portal" key="88" LabelKey="0" flags="0" rotation="0">
        <Bounds top="288.0000000" left="167.0000000" bottom="453.0000000" right="482.0000000"/>
        <PortalObj portalFla|gs="141" numOfRows="4" initialRow="2">
            <TableAliasKey>Ext.Ref.Mandanten</TableAliasKey>
            ...
```

The result should be:

```
/fmxmlsnippet/Layout/Object/PortalObj/@portalFlags
```

I only need to generate a simple XPath expression to get the idea of the XML-structure - basically the concatenation of the names of all self-or-ancestor nodes from the node represented at the cursor.

In [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148217/how-to-get-the-xpath-of-a-certain-node-when-viewing-an-xml-file-in-visual-studio) an XML Plugin for Notepad++ was suggested (which has such a function), however I am looking for an algorithm or a solution using Unix, Perl, RegEx, awk, sed or the likes which can be integrated into TextMate.